# Stream of integers

Tags: java-8

I have the code:

```
int[] values = { 1, 4, 9, 16 };
Stream<Integer> ints = Stream.of(values);
```

which gives me compilation error. But:

```
int[] values = { 1, 4, 9, 16 };
Stream<Integer> ints = Stream.of(new Integer[] {1, 4, 9, 16});
```

doesn't give so. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the first example, you are passing an array of primitives `int`s to `Stream#of` which can take either an object, or an array of object. Primitives are not objects.

In the second example, it compiles becauses you pass in an array of `Integer`.

You can use `IntStream#of` which accept `int` arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Because `int[]` and `Integer[]` is different types. First one is array of primitives, second one is array of objects with type `Integer`.

You can use `IntStream.of(int[])` or `Stream.of(Integer[])`

Answer (score 4):

A bit un-related, but the *more correct* way to do it would be :

```
Arrays.stream(values).boxed();
```